# Is there a way to curve / arc text using CSS3 / Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, css

I'm trying to make a **curved text** effect using CSS3, HTML Canvas, or even SVG (see image below for example)? Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this effect?

**Update:** To clarify: The text that will be styled this way will be dynamic.

[image: Arched or Curved Text Example]

Comment: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/web/svg_tests.php

shows what you can achieve with SVG. A good look at source may help you figure out the solution

Comment: @Gabriel, weird question: what is that font? It's delicious.

Comment: @sudowned: It's been a while, but I believe it's Futura.

Comment: Hope this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251177/curving-an-image-that-starts-as-a-rectangle-uploaded-by-user-preferably-using/29118400#29118400

Answer (score 37):

SVG supports text-on-a-path directly, though it does not 'bend' the individual glyphs along the path. Here's [an example](http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/basics/text/svg/index.htm) of how you create it:

```
...
<defs>
  <path id="textPath" d="M10 50 C10 0 90 0 90 50"/>
</defs>
<text fill="red">
  <textPath xlink:href="#textPath">Text on a Path</textPath>
</text>
...
```

Comment: Why isn't this the answer?  Seems like the best solution by far?

Answer (score 22):

You can certainly do it with canvas, try out this code as an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Testing min-width and max-width</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
      <canvas id="cnv"></canvas>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
          cnv = document.getElementById("cnv");
          cnv.width = 500;
          cnv.height = 300;
          ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");
          ctx.font = "bold 12px sans-serif";
          text = "abcdefghijklm"
          for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
              ctx.fillText(text[i], 300, 100);
              ctx.rotate(0.1);
          }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't do it exactly right, but I'm certain you'll manage to tweak it to your likening ;)

Comment: For IE you have to use excanvas: check this out http://diveintohtml5.org/canvas.html#ie

Comment: The SVG solution below seems much easier.  Why would you do it this way?

Answer (score 13):

You can do it using some CSS, however I'm sure you won't get it running on IE any time soon. On the other hand, the cool thing is that the text is selectable :D

```css
.num1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 30px) rotate(-35deg);
}
.num2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 25px) rotate(-25deg);
}
.num3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 23px) rotate(0deg);
}
.num4 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 25px) rotate(25deg);
}
.num5 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 30px) rotate(35deg);
}

span {display: inline-block; margin: 1px;}
```

```html
<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 50px auto">
    <span class="num1">a</span><span class="num2">b</span><span class="num3">c</span><span class="num4">d</span><span class="num5">e</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Frankly, I don't care about IE. This is intended for an iPhone-optimized website so I'm only worried about it displaying properly in Webkit. I might be able to pull off what you're suggesting for dynamic text using a bit of JavaScript trickery. Thanks.

Comment: IE9+ supports CSS3 2d transforms , and IE8 and below support microsoft's matrix transforms, but they're a little different in handling.

Comment: @JayC Yes and this post is 2 years old. I believe that using the `-ms-` prefix should mostly work, although I have no means to test.

Answer (score 11):

It's not a pure CSS solution but CircleType.js works great for arced text.

http://circletype.labwire.ca/

Comment: Great stuff! It works quite easily. Note that it requires another plugin ("Lettering.js is required")

Comment: it's taking lots of time to load.

Answer (score 4):

This [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150325014452/http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-text-along-arc-path/) shows you exactly how to do it using HTML5 and canvas.  One of the other answers presented a similar idea, which is to use the canvas.rotate method.  This one also uses canvas.translate.

The full code from the tutorial is:

```js
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle) {
  var len = str.length,
    s;
  context.save();
  context.translate(centerX, centerY);
  context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
  context.rotate(-1 * (angle / len) / 2);
  for (var n = 0; n < len; n++) {
    context.rotate(angle / len);
    context.save();
    context.translate(0, -1 * radius);
    s = str[n];
    context.fillText(s, 0, 0);
    context.restore();
  }
  context.restore();
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  centerX = canvas.width / 2,
  centerY = canvas.height - 30,
  angle = Math.PI * 0.8,
  radius = 150;

context.font = '30pt Calibri';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
context.lineWidth = 4;
drawTextAlongArc(context, 'Text along arc path', centerX, centerY, radius, angle);

// draw circle underneath text
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius - 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a jQuery Plugin to curve text using CSS3 called [arctext.js](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/24/arctext-js-curving-text-with-css3-and-jquery/).  It's pretty good and has a range of configuration options.  I guess it won't work on IE8 but I guess most CSS3 thing don't!

There's also a demo page with some example of it in action [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use SVG with `<textPath>` like this:

```js
function updateMessage(str) {
  document.getElementById("MyMessage").textContent = str;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="updateMessage('The text has changed');">Change the text</button>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="CurvedPath"
          d="M 0 150 Q 325 50 650 150 " />
  </defs>
  <text font-size="54" x='325' y='50'  text-anchor="middle"  fill="darkgreen" font-family=Arial,Helvetica  style="text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px gray;">
    <textPath id='MyMessage' xlink:href="#CurvedPath">THIS TEXT IS CURVED</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<embed width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml" src="path.svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <path id="textPath" d="M10 50 C10 0 90 0 90 50"/>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</embed>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the tutorial mentioned above (by Simon Tewsi) to write a better solution, regarding the kerning issue. Uses no library, pure JS.

See it at http://jsfiddle.net/fidnut/cjccg74f/

```
function drawTextAlongArcInside(ctx, str, font, color, radius, angle, centerX, centerY, wspace)
```

Note: SO is demanding that I put all the code from JSFiddle in here too. I don't think this is wise, too much code, so I am adding only the name of the function.

Answer (score -1):

There is also `transform: skew(x, y)`, which does not use canvas.

Comment: Does not generate the desired results.