# curved text (not image)

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to curve / arc text using CSS3 / Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840862/is-there-a-way-to-curve-arc-text-using-css3-canvas)

Need to created a curved/arched text using jQuery.

If is not possible with jQuery, can this be done using css3?

[image: curved text screenshot]