# HTML problem of text for shape

Tags: html

I have 1 big text .generally text is always is in horizontal line shape.Is there any way to make it the curve type of shape?

Answer (score 0):

See this [article](http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/#transform_rotate)

Using css transform you can rotate text

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Canvas to accomplish this.
This post should have the information you need [is-there-a-way-to-curve-arc-text-using-css3-canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840862/is-there-a-way-to-curve-arc-text-using-css3-canvas)