# Jquery Example:curving text

Tags: jquery

I am engraving a product and I am trying to engrave text in curve dynamically but I am unable to do it.Means Whenever I am writing into text it will print on product image in curved shape.I want only 'Top Center' and 'Bottom Center' in curved shape.see following link.

http://dwfek.hmnjw.servertrust.com/v/vspfiles/assets/images/Engraving%20Demo/engraving.html

Comment: This may help: http://blog.betabong.com/2010/05/13/jquery-plugin-round-text/

Comment: Check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766901/curving-text-with-jquery-no-hardcoding