# Draw rotated text on curved path

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'd like to display a text on a curved line. Each letter of the text should be rotated in order to be orthogonal to the curve.

The only ready-made plugin I've found is [Arctext](http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/) from tympanus. Unfortunatelly it only renders text based on a radius.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

[image: curved image demo]

I don't have limitations on what to use, neither cross-browser compatibility is an issue. Only thing needed is that this "thing" shouldn't be made in the server side. It should be updated (after text change) directly on the client.

**edit: More info**

1. Text rendered would be set from the end user.
2. Custom fonts will be used. Cufon probably.

Comment: If Firefox-only is okay, Firefox has [mozTextAlongPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas#mozTextAlongPath.28.29) for `<canvas>`.

Comment: SVG can do this. For example: http://www.itk.ilstu.edu/faculty/javila/SVG/SVG_drawing1/text_path.htm

Comment: @thirtydot thanks. I've added more info. Svg can do this but it is static.

Comment: @minitech I wasn't aware of this, thanks. I've added more info on the requirements.

Comment: @odyodyodys: SVG doesn't have to be static. You can embed it in HTML and manipulate it just like regular elements. (And you still haven't said if it's possible to just support Firefox - because if it is, `mozTextAlongPath` fulfills both current requirements.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840862/is-there-a-way-to-curve-arc-text-using-css3-canvas might help and made a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xUxG6/9/ goof luck B-)

Comment: Can I use cufon fonts with Svg? I believe not