# get aspect ratio of axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an easy and reliable way to determine the current aspect ratio of an `axes` when its aspect is set to `'auto'`?

The obvious thing to check is `ax.get_aspect()`, but that just returns `'auto'`. I can set it to an arbitrary constant value by `ax.set_aspect(aspect)`, after which that same constant is returned by `ax.get_aspect()`. By default (and very usefully) we have `aspect = 'auto'`, in which case the aspect ratio is automatically calculated and adjusted to match the data limits and axes size.
**How can I get the numeric aspect ratio that was automatically selected?**

To clarify, this is neither the aspect ratio of the *data limits* returned by `ax.get_data_ratio()`, nor the aspect ratio of the *display size* of the figure or subplot returned by `fig.get_figheight() / fig.get_figwidth()` (for the figure). It's a bit subtle, as it depends on both the display size and the data limits. (Which can lead to confusing the different ratios and the reason I find it important to have it easily accessible.)

Comment: What aspect ratio are you referring to? Data or display?

Comment: Based on your comment to @Frank's answer, I am going to guess display or something more complex.

Comment: It's "something more complex," unfortunately, @MadPhysicist. See my edited question.

Comment: I almost got you an answer. Hang on a sec.

Comment: Sorry that yesterday I was too tired to realize that my solution just works in case of aspect='equal', but your are asking for the other cases. Since there doesn't seem to be a simple method for getting this, I have requested this feature: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8013

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Hi @tacaswell, I used it to calculate the `rotation` angle for `ax.annotate`. Being able to set the *slope* of text (in data units) would solve the same problem for my case.

Comment: Have a look at the contour labeling code which does something similar, but I am not sure exactly how it does it under the hood.

Comment: @tacaswell I actually ran across that, there is a subclass of `Text`, but I could not find an easy way to use it. I'll look deeper.

Comment: Please select an answer when you get a chance

Answer (score 18):

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-aspect), the aspect ratio is the ratio of data-to-display scaling units in the x- and y-axes. i.e., if there are 10 data units per display in the y-direction and 1 data unit per display unit in the x-direction, the ratio would be 1/10. The circle would be 10 times wider than it is tall. This corresponds to the statement that an aspect of `num` does the following:

> a circle will be stretched such that the height is num times the width. aspect=1 is the same as aspect=’equal’.

Based on the same original piece of code that you looked at ([`matplotlib.axes._base.adjust_aspect`, starting around line 1405](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/8b630a4ef25b803695212528b407cad150afb140/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L1405)), I think we can come up with a simplified formula as long as you only need this ratio for linear Cartesian axes. Things get complicated with polar and logarithmic axes, so I will ignore them.

To reiterate the formula:

```
(x_data_unit / x_display_unit) / (y_data_unit / y_display_unit)
```

This happens to be the same as

```
(y_display_unit / x_display_unit) / (y_data_unit / x_data_unit)
```

This last formulation is just the ratio of the display sizes in the two directions divided by the ratio of the x and y limits. Note that `ax.get_data_ratio` does *NOT* apply here because that returns the results for the actual data bounds, not the axis limits at all:

```
from operator import sub
def get_aspect(ax):
    # Total figure size
    figW, figH = ax.get_figure().get_size_inches()
    # Axis size on figure
    _, _, w, h = ax.get_position().bounds
    # Ratio of display units
    disp_ratio = (figH * h) / (figW * w)
    # Ratio of data units
    # Negative over negative because of the order of subtraction
    data_ratio = sub(*ax.get_ylim()) / sub(*ax.get_xlim())

    return disp_ratio / data_ratio
```

Now let's test it:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
print('{} == {}'.format(ax.get_aspect(), get_aspect(ax)))
ax.set_aspect(10)
print('{} == {}'.format(ax.get_aspect(), get_aspect(ax)))
```

Comment: This works.  I am surprised there is no easier way to do that.  I wonder why `matplotlib` does not provide `get_aspect` function.

Comment: @Pygmalion. It's a very niche application.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You need that value every time you want to draw a circle. I don't know if it's that niche.

Comment: @Guimoute. This is getting the aspect ratio. You just need `set_aspect('equal')` to draw a circle. So I'd say my comment aged reasonably well.

Comment: Yes but `set_aspect("equal")` is not a universal solution. In many cases you might want to work on circles in an already existing canvas with a given and constant aspect ratio. For example, I stumbled upon here because I'm writing a function to get the closest data point to my cursor, and of course I did not anticipate that `sqrt(dx² + dy²)` is not an acceptable definition of distance because of the changing data limits and figure ratios. I'm looking at a circle in display units which is an ellipsis in data units. **Edit:** so your solution is perfect for that and `dx /= get_aspect(ax)` works.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing I can find is this:

```
def get_aspect(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    fig = ax.figure

    ll, ur = ax.get_position() * fig.get_size_inches()
    width, height = ur - ll
    axes_ratio = height / width
    aspect = axes_ratio / ax.get_data_ratio()

    return aspect
```

But it's surprisingly complicated, and I'm not sure if it is reliable under transforms, etc, as I know nothing about the `bbox` and `transform` objects.

Comment: I feel like you should add this to your question and ask if there is a easier or more reliable way than this

Comment: This code looks approximately like the code in `Axes.apply_aspect` in matplotlib itself.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
import numpy as np
aspect = sum(np.abs(ax.get_xlim())) / sum(np.abs(ax.get_ylim()))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Frank, but I believe that just gives `1/ax.get_data_ratio()`.

Comment: Oh that's right and even better than my suggestion. I didn't know this existed. I thought that's what your are looking for but apparently its something else. Sorry.

Comment: why `np.abs()` ? This won't work if both limits have the same sign.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it does exactly what you want, but try it

```
    bbox = axis.get_window_extent().transformed(figure.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
    aspect_ratio = bbox.width / bbox.height
```