# Spectrogram Colorbar as subplot plotted but size not reflecting

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to get a Spectrogram plot with colorbar like this for a `.wav` file:

[image: Desired Spectrogram With Colorbar Output]

So, I wrote the following:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from scipy.io.wavfile import read as readWav

wavfile1 = 'Speech.wav'
wavFs, wavData = readWav(wavfile1)

figSG = Figure(figsize=[15, 8], facecolor='lightgrey')
axSG = figSG.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, position=[0, 0, 1, 0.85])
axCB = figSG.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, position=[0.2, 0.0, 0.6, 0.05])
pltlinescurves = axSG.specgram(wavData, NFFT=256, Fs=8000)
figSG.colorbar(pltlinescurves[3], label='Intensity (in dB)', cax=axCB, orientation='horizontal')
```

which gives me this:

[image: My Output]

As evident from the code above, I have added the `position` argument as mentioned [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot), as per my understanding is same as:

```
axSG = figSG.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 0.85])
axCB = figSG.add_axes([0.2, 0.0, 0.6, 0.05])
```

Is my understanding wrong? If yes, how do I achieve this using subplots?

**P.S.**: For my implementation convenience, I'm avoiding `pyplot` and dealing with `Figure` and `Axes` classes.

Comment: Yes, the position argument is ignored, because you told the add_subplot command to add a subplot at 2,1,2.  If you insist on using subplots `axs = fig.subplots(2, 1, gridspc_kw = {‘height_ratio’: [1, 0.1]})` may be what you are after.  But why not just place the colorbar with fig.colorbar?

Comment: Oh. Okay. `axs = fig.subplots(2, 1, gridspc_kw = {‘height_ratio’: [1, 0.1]})` throws the error `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no property 'gridspc_kw'`.

Comment: I would like to manipulate the colorbar with Axes properties (say, a title, ticks etc.). That's why I'm trying to use subplot.

Comment: You can manipulate the title ticks etc on a colorbar.  That axes is just `cb.ax`

Comment: ... and yes, I had a typo, gridspc_kw->gridspec_kw. The docs for `subplots` are available: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots

Comment: Great. That was helpful. This statement `axSG, axCB = figSG.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 0.1], 'width_ratios': [1]})` solved the issue partially.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245242/discussion-between-skrowten-hermit-and-jody-klymak).

Answer (score 1):

The *usual* way to do this is

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[15, 8], layout='constrained')
cb = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(100, 300))
ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax.set_ylabel('f [Hz]')
ax.set_title('Spectrogram')

fig.colorbar(cb, ax=ax, label='Intensity in dB', 
             location='bottom', shrink=0.75, aspect=50, pad=0.02)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use Jody's inputs above and solve the problem partially:

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from scipy.io.wavfile import read as readWav

wavfile1 = 'Speech.wav'
wavFs, wavData = readWav(wavfile1)

figSG = Figure(figsize=[15, 8], facecolor='lightgrey')
axSG, axCB = figSG.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1, 0.1], 'width_ratios': [1]})
axSG.set_xlabel('Time (s)', fontsize=14)
axSG.set_ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', fontsize=14)
axSG.set_title('Spectrogram (Hz vs s)', fontsize=18)
pltlinescurves = axSG.specgram(wavData, NFFT=256, Fs=wavFs)
cbar = figSG.colorbar(pltlinescurves[3], cax=axCB, orientation='horizontal', pad=1.5)
cbar.set_label('Intensity (in dB)',size=14)
cbaspect = get_aspect(ax=axCB) * 0.5
axCB.set_aspect(cbaspect, anchor='C')
figSG.tight_layout()
```

where the function `get_aspect()` used above is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41597178/4230964) and is defined as:

```
def get_aspect(ax):
    fig = ax.figure

    ll, ur = ax.get_position() * fig.get_size_inches()
    width, height = ur - ll
    axes_ratio = height / width
    aspect = axes_ratio / ax.get_data_ratio()

    return aspect
```

which gives me the following output:

[image: ParitalOutputSolution]

Still, I'm unable to shrink the colorbar (to about 75%-85% would be ideal) as shown in the post above. Any leads would be much appreciated.