# Circumferential radius labels python

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I am plotting polar data, however the radial tick marks are quite messy given the magnitude. Is there any way to have the radial tick numbers wrapping around the circumference of the ticks?

I attempted to fake this by setting the radial label position to 90 degrees (see below) using ax.set_rlabel_position(), however this also looks off as the numbers aren't centered properly.

[image]

Comment: There certainly is. @ThomasKühn wrote a nice [`CurvedText` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353576/curved-text-rendering-in-matplotlib) to plot text along a curve. So you would need to subclass the `PolarAxes` and add the curved text to its ticklabels. While this is sure possible, it might not be worth the effort. But if you try it and get stuck at some point, one may sure help you out if you provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Also some other ideas:  turn off every other ticklabel, Multiply them all by 100 to make the number more human readable.