# how to generate curved text

Tags: python, database, text, deep-learning

I'm trying to create curved text images with python as fake image to train my network.

sample desired image : [image: sample]
I tried using [TextRecognitionDataGenerator](https://github.com/Belval/TextRecognitionDataGenerator) but it's output wrap characters but I want characters to be on curve not distorted. 
I saw also this example [matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353576/curved-text-rendering-in-matplotlib) but can't work on it. I can create  with photoshop but because of large amount of images it is impossible.

regards

Comment: What have you tried ? I would do it by generating svg images. You have everything you need here : https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_text.asp

Comment: Then you should be able to make it in svg. You'll just have to generate the text letter by letter and to compute each time the top left position and rotation.

Comment: thanks. I want to create image with desired text. my image counts is over 10000000 with desired text. and want to create python script and generate them with one time run.