# Curve text around a polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations, polar-plot

I am trying to curve text on a polar chart in matplotlib.

Here is an example of my case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
   
text = ["Electoral Process", "Political Pluralism", "Rule of Law",
            "Freedom of expression", "Freedom of believe"]

no_labels =len(text)
angle_size = int(360/no_labels)
#define the number of angles in degrees and convert it to radians 
theta = [i/180*np.pi for i in range(0, 360,angle_size) ]
#where to put the labels on the radial axis
radius = [1]*no_labels
#Find the mid point of each angle
mid_point =[i/180*np.pi for i in range(int(angle_size/2), 360, angle_size)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'},figsize=(10, 6), facecolor="white")

ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_xticklabels([]) #remove the original xlabels
ax.set_yticklabels([])  #remove the original ylabels

# Arrange the grid into number of sales equal parts in degrees
lines = plt.thetagrids(range(0, 360, int(360/len(text))))

#Place the text in the midle of each pie
for m, r, t in zip(mid_point,radius, text):
    ax.annotate(t, xy=[m, r], fontsize=12,  ha="center", va="center",  )
```

Which generates this:

[image]

I have found other posts that do that, but I dont understand the code so I am trying to build it from scratch.
This is what I got so far:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib as mpl 

text = ["Electoral Process", "Political Pluralism", "Rule of Law",
            "Freedom of expression", "Freedom of believe"]

no_labels =len(text)
angle_size = int(360/no_labels)
#define the number of angles in degrees and convert it to radians 
theta = [i/180*np.pi for i in range(0, 360,angle_size) ]
#where to put the labels on the radial axis
radius = [1]*no_labels
#Find the mid point of each angle
mid_point =[i/180*np.pi for i in range(int(angle_size/2), 360, angle_size)]

fig,ax=plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'},figsize=(10,6), dpi=100)


# Arrange the grid into number of sales equal parts in degrees
lines = plt.thetagrids(range(0, 360, int(360/len(text))))

ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_xticklabels([]) #remove the original xlabels
ax.set_yticklabels([])  #remove the original ylabels

#start with one label

start_text = theta[0]
text2=["ELECTORAL PROCESS"]
spacing=len(text[0])+4
end_text = theta[1]

x= np.linspace(start_text, end_text, spacing)
y= [1, 0.5]

for txt in text2:
    print(txt)
    for a,tx in zip(x,txt):
        ax.text(a, 1.05 ,tx,rotation=-28, fontsize= 8, ha="center", va= "center"),
print(a,tx)
```

Which produces this:
[image]

Now I have to iterate it for every label, rotate each letter to follow the curve (using a hardcoded angle at the moment) and also write upwards or downwards depending on where the code is and it seems like I might be complicating things.

Anyone has done this using "simple code" or can explain how the code below works?

[Similar problem but dont understand the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61844673/how-do-i-curve-text-in-a-polar-plot)

Comment: See [ask]. Focus on a single specific problem. What have you tried? What part of the linked code are you asking on?

Comment: Just asking to curve the text shown in the first image. 
The second code I show is what I have tried.
The code I would like to build on is the first one.

Comment: You need to be specific. You just said "explain how the code below works". What part of the code don't you understand? Did you try applying that code?

Comment: The part where it curves the text. Because I dont understand it, I dont know how to apply it to my code.

Comment: I said you need to be SPECIFIC. For example, do you know the meaning of the ```x``` and ```y``` arguments of the ```CurvedText.__init__()``` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521963/1186624)? If you don't know, add ```print([x, y])``` and run the code.

Comment: Let me put it this way, can you apply the curvedText function to the first code I posted? That way I can easily test the code and have a chance to understand it. Greatly appreciated if you are able to do that :)

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Question and answer should be clear and specific so others can easily search them for similar problems. Applying the generic module to your specific case is just creating another duplicate.

Comment: I am not asking for free coding (this is a pet project of mine and I do not do python for a living, only for fun), just asking to remove the complexity of the original code and move it to a simplified version so I can have a chance to understand it.
If you cant help, that is fine, I will leave the question up in case someone else can figure it out and have the time to help, or I will update the code once I get it myself.
Have a nice day regardless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @aradhna I managed to fix the code. (Thanks a million)
Here it is!

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = ["Electoral Process", "Political Pluralism", "Rule of Law",
            "Freedom of expression", "Freedom of believe"]

no_labels =len(text)
angle_size = int(360/no_labels)
#define the number of angles in degrees and convert it to radians 
theta = [i/180*np.pi for i in range(0, 360,angle_size) ]
#Find the mid point of each angle
mid_point =[i/180*np.pi for i in range(int(angle_size/2), 360, angle_size)]

fig,ax=plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'},figsize=(10,6), dpi=100)


# Arrange the grid into number of text
lines = plt.thetagrids(range(0, 360, int(360/len(text))))


ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_xticklabels([]) #remove the original xlabels
ax.set_yticklabels([])  #remove the original ylabels

for txt,  midpoint in zip(text, mid_point):
    #count nr letters divide by 2 convert to radians and substract from midpoiint
    center_pos = midpoint-np.deg2rad(len(txt)/2+4)
    #print(midpoint, text, a)
    for i in range(len(txt)):     
        #print(txt[i], midpoint, a)      
        ax.text(center_pos, 1.04 ,txt[i].capitalize(),rotation=-np.rad2deg(center_pos), fontsize= 8, ha="center", va= "center")
        center_pos += 0.032 #adds radians to the next275 letter
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: I am glad it worked !

Comment: Would not have been able to do it without your help. Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hard question and this is what I got after 2 hours of coding (I could not do better).

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# ------------------------------------ # 
  
# Define the figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
# Setting the axes projection as polar 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

# List that stores 
# - the text to be displayed 
# - the distance, r, from the center
# - the angle at which to display the text
# 
# data = [["text", r, theta in deg], [...], ...]
#  The r and theta have to be hardcoded
#
data = [["Electoral Process",  1.02, 65.0], ["Political Pluralism", 1.04,  -5.0], ["Rule of Law", 1.06, -95.0],
        ["Freedom of expression", 1.06, 215.0], ["Freedom of believe", 1.06, 137.0]]

# Arrange the grid into number of sales equal parts in degrees
lines = plt.thetagrids(range(0, 360, int(360/len(data))))

# Iterate through each text
for text, r, theta in data:

     # Convert to radians
     theta = np.deg2rad(theta)

     # Iterate through each letter
     for i in range(len(text)):
          
          # Display the letter
          #
          # The angle of rotation is -(90 deg - theta). 
          # This makes a right angle triangle. We must rotate the text towards Center. 
          # Please draw it on paper, with the angle, theta, to get why the equation is correct.
          # 
          #                      text[i]
          #                        |
          #                        |
          # Center ----------------|
          # 
          plt.text(theta, r, text[i], rotation=-(90-np.rad2deg(theta)), fontsize=16)

          # Decrement theta for the next letter
          theta -= 0.06  # Arbirary value

# Remove tick labels
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Here is the result :
[image: Figure]

I hope this helps you.

Comment: It definitely does! I will try your code and if I manage to improve it I will post back.
Have a fantastic weekend :)))