# How can I draw a curved text using python? Converting text to curved image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library

I want to write a python program that converts given text into an image. There are tutorials for it online, but I want to curve the text over a circle.

Let's say I have the text "YOUR CURVED TEXT".

I want to draw this on an image and end up with something like following:

[image: Final result after processing the image]

I checked Pillow and OpenCV. I might be making a mistake but I don't think they have any functionality for curving the given text?

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think it's helpfull
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521963/9885352)

Comment: If you want vector files, you might want some kind of SVG solution. [SVGWrite](https://github.com/mozman/svgwrite) is not being actively developed, but it does have a [TextPath](https://svgwrite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/text.html#textpath) method which will do what you want. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) has an [extension system](https://inkscape-extensions-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which is based on Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that in ImageMagick using -distort arc 360.

```
convert -font Arial -pointsize 20 label:' Your Curved Text  Your Curved Text ' -virtual-pixel Background  -background white -distort Arc 360  -rotate -90  arc_circle_text.jpg
```

[image]

You can do that also in Python Wand, which uses ImageMagick as follows:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.font import Font
from wand.display import display

with Image() as img:
    img.background_color = 'white'
    img.font = Font('Arial', 20)
    img.read(filename='label: Your Curved Text  Your Curved Text ')
    img.virtual_pixel = 'white'
    # 360 degree arc, rotated -90 degrees
    img.distort('arc', (360,-90))
    img.save(filename='arc_text.png')
    img.format = 'png'
    display(img)
```

[image]

Thanks to Eric McConville for helping with the label: code.

Comment: Thanks. I never used wand before. I am glad I learned about it.

Answer (score 4):

thanks to [fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7355741/fmw42) for the answer above. I slightly modified this to allow for a transparent background and to do negative angles as well. My first submission to give back to this wonderful community :)

```
import wand

def curved_text_to_image(
text: str,
font_filepath: str,
font_size: int,
color: str,  #assumes hex string
curve_degree: int):
"""
Uses ImageMagik / wand - so have to ensure its installed.
"""
with wand.image.Image(width=1, height=1, resolution=(600, 600)) as img: # open an image
    with wand.drawing.Drawing() as draw:   # open a drawing objetc
        # assign font details
        draw.font = font_filepath
        draw.font_size = font_size
        draw.fill_color = wand.color.Color(color)
        # get size of text
        metrics = draw.get_font_metrics(img, text)
        height, width = int(metrics.text_height), int(metrics.text_width)
        # resize the image
        img.resize(width=width, height=height)
        # draw the text
        draw.text(0, height, text)
        draw(img)
        img.virtual_pixel = 'transparent'
        # curve_degree arc, rotated 0 degrees - ie at the top
        if curve_degree >= 0:
            img.distort('arc', (curve_degree, 0))
        else:
            # rotate it 180 degrees, then distory and rotate back 180 degrees
            img.rotate(180)
            img.distort('arc', (abs(curve_degree), 180))
        img.format = 'png'
        wand.display.display(img)
return img
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on the same problem, and could achieve very crude transparent PNG output just using PIL. This could be a decent starting point if you want to stick to PIL, feel free to optimise it further. Hope this helps someone.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImagePath
import math
import random


def draw_rotated_text(img, text, position, font, t_angle, fill):
    # Create a new blank image with a transparent background
    text_image = Image.new("RGBA", (img.width//10,img.height//10), (0, 0, 0, 0))

    # Get a new drawing context for the text image
    text_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(text_image)

    # Draw the text on the text image
    text_draw.text((0, 0), text, font=font, fill=fill)

    # Rotate the text image
    rotated_text_image = text_image.rotate(t_angle, expand=True,center=(15,15))

    # Get the transparency mask of the rotated text image
    mask = rotated_text_image.split()[3]

    # Paste the rotated text image onto the original image
    #draw.im.paste(rotated_text_image, position, rotated_text_image)
    img.paste(rotated_text_image, (position[0], position[1], position[0] + rotated_text_image.width, position[1] + rotated_text_image.height), rotated_text_image)
    #draw.im.paste(mask, (position[0], position[1], position[0] + rotated_text_image.width, position[1] + rotated_text_image.height), rotated_text_image)
    #img.paste( ImageOps.colorize(rotated_text_image, (0,0,0), (255,255,84)), (242,60),  rotated_text_image)


def draw_text_circular(draw, img, text, font, radius, center_x, center_y, start_angle, text_color):
    # Iterate over each character in the text
    for char in text:
        # Calculate the position of the character along the circular path
        angle = math.radians(start_angle)
        x = center_x + int(radius * math.cos(angle))
        y = center_y + int(radius * math.sin(angle))

        #draw.text((x, y), char, font=font, fill=text_color)
        char_rotation_angle = 270-start_angle
        draw_rotated_text(img, char, (x, y), font, char_rotation_angle, text_color)
        # Increment the angle for the next character
        start_angle += 180 / len(text)

def circular_design(line, font_path):
    # Create a blank image with an RGBA mode for transparency
    img = Image.new('RGBA', (800, 800), color=(255, 255, 255, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # Center of the circular path
    center_x, center_y = img.width // 2, img.height // 2

    # Radius of the circular path
    radius = 300

    # Starting angle for the text
    start_angle = 180

    # Load the font
    font_size = 50  # You can adjust the font size
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, size=font_size)

    # Get a random light color (pastel colors)
    text_color = (25,25,25, 255)

    # Draw text in a circular path
    draw_text_circular(draw, img, line, font, radius, center_x, center_y, start_angle, text_color)

    # Save or display the result
    img.save("circular_text.png")
    img.show()


# Example usage
line = "Your quote goes here Customize as needed"
font_path = r"c:\windows\fonts\DEADJIM.TTF"  # Replace with the actual path to your font file
circular_design(line, font_path)
```

Output:
[image: output]