# Draw text around image in semicircular path in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, wand

I need to write/draw some text of the objects in an image around semicircular path, I have used ImageMagic/Wand using the image.distort method but it works for longer text, if the text is small it looks bad. Is there a way in PIL or ImageMagic/Wand to achieve that.
I am looking for something like this image.
[image]
I have already tried suggestions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68979045/how-can-i-draw-a-curved-text-using-python-converting-text-to-curved-image) but it does not work for all text lengths. Also when I paste the text image on original image, it does not align to center

[image: long text example]
[image: short text example]

Comment: Please show an example that looks bad and your imagemagick command line. Have you tried padding your text with blank spaces to make it longer?

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am using imagemagick/wand in python application, and the code I am using is linked in the original question. I have added the example how it looks now.

Answer (score 1):

You can pad the text with spaces in Imagemagick.

```
convert -font Arial -pointsize 20 label:' Your Curved Text  Your Curved Text ' -virtual-pixel Background  -background white -distort Arc 360  -rotate -90  arc_circle_text.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert -font Arial -pointsize 20 label:' Text                               ' -virtual-pixel Background  -background white -distort Arc 360  -rotate -90  arc_circle_text2.jpg
```

[image]