# Drawing text along an arbitrary path using matplotlib TextPath

Tags: python, matplotlib

Similar to drawing text along an arbitrary path using SVG `textPath`, I would like to do something similar using `matplotlib` From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521963/1634986), it is possible to do by subclassing the `Text` class. However, I'd like to use `TextPath` instead as it scales better as the plot domain changes. The following example is not very general, but at least it shows the basic idea.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import text as mtext
from matplotlib import patches as mpatch
from matplotlib import transforms as mtrans

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7, 7), dpi=100)

N = 100
cx = -np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N))
cy = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N))

ax.plot(cx, cy, color='black')

tpath = mtext.TextPath((0, 0), 'T', .5)
tw = tpath.get_extents().width
th = tpath.get_extents().height
angle = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(cy[0], cx[0]))
tpath = tpath.transformed(
    mtrans.Affine2D()
    .translate(-0.5 * tw, -0.5 * th)
    .rotate_deg(angle - 90)
    .translate(cx[0], cy[0])
)

tpath2 = mtext.TextPath((0, 0), 'E', .5)
tw2 = tpath2.get_extents().width
th2 = tpath2.get_extents().height
angle2 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(cy[5], cx[5]))
tpath2 = tpath2.transformed(
    mtrans.Affine2D()
    .translate(-0.5 * tw, -0.5 * th)
    .rotate_deg(angle2 - 90)
    .translate(cx[5], cy[5])
)

tpath3 = mtext.TextPath((0, 0), 'S', .5)
tw3 = tpath3.get_extents().width
th3 = tpath3.get_extents().height
angle3 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(cy[11], cx[11]))
tpath3 = tpath3.transformed(
    mtrans.Affine2D()
    .translate(-0.5 * tw, -0.5 * th)
    .rotate_deg(angle3 - 90)
    .translate(cx[11], cy[11])
)

tpath4 = mtext.TextPath((0, 0), 'T', .5)
tw4 = tpath4.get_extents().width
th4 = tpath4.get_extents().height
angle4 = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(cy[16], cx[16]))
tpath4 = tpath4.transformed(
    mtrans.Affine2D()
    .translate(-0.5 * tw, -0.5 * th)
    .rotate_deg(angle4 - 90)
    .translate(cx[16], cy[16])
)

tpatch = mpatch.PathPatch(tpath, facecolor='red', edgecolor='black',
                          linewidth=3)
tpatch2 = mpatch.PathPatch(tpath2, facecolor='red', edgecolor='black',
                           linewidth=3)
tpatch3 = mpatch.PathPatch(tpath3, facecolor='red', edgecolor='black',
                           linewidth=3)
tpatch4 = mpatch.PathPatch(tpath4, facecolor='red', edgecolor='black',
                           linewidth=3)

ax.add_patch(tpatch)
ax.add_patch(tpatch2)
ax.add_patch(tpatch3)
ax.add_patch(tpatch4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Obviously, the spaing of the text in this example is hard-coded. To generalize this, you would need to take any path and be able to calculate the angles at various points where the text will go. In order to do that, you will need to have some idea of the size of the text to properly space it. One thought I had was to perhaps subclass `TextPath` or create a `Path` subclass that can be handled by `TextToPath`. Looking at the source code for those classes shows the use of the `matplotlib._text_helpers` module that has methods to calculate the text size. What I do not understand is what units the text sizes are calculated in. I think it might be pixels, but I cannot be sure as it is not documented anywhere.

I am hoping there is someone who has a better idea about how to handle the text size issue. Beyond that, any other ideas on how to approach adding text along a curved path would also be appreciated.

Comment: You might get inspiration from the [source code](https://github.com/rougier/scientific-visualization-book/blob/master/code/showcases/text-spiral.py) of the "text-spiral" showcase found page 198 of the book [rougier/scientific-visualization-book](https://github.com/rougier/scientific-visualization-book).