# Curved Menu in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been given a file by a designer that I'm required to develop. They're asking me to do a curved/arching menu:

[image]

Is this possible to create? I've never come across something like this before and am baffled as to approach this.

Comment: Is slicing it into smaller images instead of using text an option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be able to do it with `canvas`. See the answer to [Is there a way to curve / arc text using CSS3 / Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840862/is-there-a-way-to-curve-arc-text-using-css3-canvas) for a sample.  Note that `canvas` is not supported by IE8 and earlier, but it is otherwise pretty widely supported in modern browsers.

You might also want to look at this tutorial on [drawing a sine wave with `canvas`](http://www.johnpezzetti.com/2011/01/25/html5-canvas-tutorial-creating-a-2-dimensional-wave) since the menu in your image is somewhat sine wave shaped.

That's a lot of work though for something like this, though.  Instead, you can just make it a big image and use a `map` element to make an image map.

You could also consturct it out of a series of small images.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into examples using CSS3's `rotation` property:

https://www.google.com/search?q=css+rotate

https://www.google.com/search?q=css+rotate+menu

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

Comment: Is it possible to do this with wordpress' dynamic menu? if not i there a way to turn this off?

Comment: doesnt rotate menu literally rotate the menu, rather than curve text? i dont think it can actually bend it, just rotate it on an axis point.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't possible using CSS at all. It would have to be created using sliced images or done in flash.

Comment: I think it's possible with CSS3 and even IE filters, although difficult. At least the text part.

Comment: I'm using wordpress to develop the site, so I'm guessing slicing the images won't be possible because I'll using their dynamic menu.

Comment: then i don't think it's possible. if you look at @Trott's answer about canvas' and drawing on a sine wave you may be able to get it going but it will definitely take a lot of work, probably more than it's worth.