# How to put text in a circular div?

Tags: html, css, curve

I need to have a div (Pink Color Area) with  some text in it. **See the image Below**

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840862/is-there-a-way-to-curve-arc-text-using-css3-canvas

Answer (score 2):

here is ARCTEXT.JS plugin, you can use this plugin from here :
http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/

You just enter your text, set the curbe, and copy the CSS :)

But, it's not really optimized...