# Provide text shape to active object (text) on canvas in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to provide text shape to active text object added on Canvas of HTML5.
I have made demo site : http://dstudio.edreamz.in/Sample_tshirt_app/Tshirt_test.htm

I want to apply Curve text effect like

[image]

So please tell me what could I use there ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Is there a way to curve / arc text using CSS3 / Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840862/is-there-a-way-to-curve-arc-text-using-css3-canvas)

Comment: maybe search google (or, bing) for libraries that have this fucntionality?