# CSS how to warp/bend an image or div?

Tags: css, curve

Hi,

Is it possible to achieve this effect with CSS only?

[image]

As you can see, the image on top is distorted along with the text inside to look like the one below. It may be a div or an image. I have been researching on transform but found nothing about curves.

This is NOT a duplicate because I am not asking how to curve the text only but the div container as well as in case of an image.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to curve / arc text using CSS3 / Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840862/is-there-a-way-to-curve-arc-text-using-css3-canvas). See the 3rd answer for the pure CSS way.

Comment: HTML5 Canvas would make sense in your situation

Comment: svg does it too ... or an img with an alt attribute  to make sure it is seen everywhere:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you would technically qualify this as "CSS only" since it is using an SVG filter, but I think it could be made to achieve the type of warping you want.

```css
.warped {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 4px;
  filter: url(#displacement);
}
#filterSource {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="warped">Warped Text!</span>
<div>
  <svg id="filterSource" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="displacement" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <!-- this is just a base64 encoded PNG with a simple linear gradient -->
      <!-- this may not be exactly what you want, but you can adjust the R and B channels to displace the element however you like. -->
      <feImage href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAACXBIWXMAAAdhAAAHYQGVw7i2AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQB3d3cuaW5rc2NhcGUub3Jnm+48GgAAAGlJREFUaIHtz6ENwEAMxVBfUWn3H7Kw8LpCdMjAT/osIF7AZuAGnsMt4D3cN3kOuIZ3eoXYFGJTiE0hNoXYFGJTiE0hNoXYFGJTiE0hNoXYFGJTiE0hNoXYFGJTiE0hNoXYFGJTiE0hNj9ceBBjuV6HJAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" result="dispMap" />
      <feDisplacementMap
        in="SourceGraphic"
        in2="dispMap"
        scale="10"
        xChannelSelector="B"
        yChannelSelector="R" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Here's a nice tutorial on some cool effects you can achieve with this technique: https://www.creativebloq.com/how-to/add-svg-filters-with-css